# Did HashMap state is cached in multithreaded app?

Tags: java, multithreading, caching

Can we consider what next code is thread safe? In particular can storage.get(word) method return some cached value? 
Or in thread can be cached only object referense, but object state is non-cached? I tried search some java specs, but this did not succeed. Ty.

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> storage = new HashMap<>();

public synchronized void addWord(String word) {
    Integer integer = storage.get(word);
    if (integer == null) {
        storage.put(word, 1);
    } else {
        storage.put(word, integer + 1);
    }
    logger.info(storage);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _cached_? Also, is access to `storage` always wrapped with a `synchronized` block?

Answer (score 0):

You need Synchronization or other means to ensure visibility to other node.
When you execute your critical section inside a monitor two things ensure

1.**Atomicity**: At a time one thread able to execute the critical section so avoid race condition.

2.**Visibility**: Releasing a lock forces a flush of all writes from working memory employed by the thread, and acquiring a lock forces a (re)load of the values of accessible fields.

Answer (score -1):

OK, right answer:
 JSR-133:
But there is more to synchronization than mutual exclusion. Synchronization ensures that memory writes by a thread before or during a synchronized block are made visible in a predictable manner to other threads which synchronize on the same monitor. After we exit a synchronized block, we release the monitor, which has the effect of flushing the cache to main memory, so that writes made by this thread can be visible to other threads. Before we can enter a synchronized block, we acquire the monitor, which has the effect of invalidating the local processor cache so that variables will be reloaded from main memory. We will then be able to see all of the writes made visible by the previous release.

ty all